# $n\ge 8\,\Rightarrow\, n = 3j + 5k\ $ for $\,j,k,n\in \Bbb N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

I'm new to Math Induction, I don't know how it goes from $ + 1 = 3 + 5 + 1$ into $5 = 5 − 5 + 5.$

**I'm trying to prove that:**

Any whole number of at least 8 cents
can be obtained using coins of 3 and 5 cents

**Assume**: There is a number $$ for which there are $$ and $$ such that $ = 3 + 5$

**Here's my working:**

$ = 3 + 5$

Therefore $ + 1 = 3 + 5 + 1$

$5 = 5 − 5 + 5$

$5 = 5  − 1 + 5$

$ + 1 = 3 + 5 + 1$

$ + 1 = 3 + 5( − 1) + 5 + 1$

$ + 1 = 3 + 5( − 1) + 6$

$ + 1 = 3( + 2) + 5( − 1)$

$ +  = ' + '$

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  It would help if you stated what you are trying to prove by induction; also it would be better if you use a different symbol from $x$ for $x+2$

Comment: @J.W.Tanner Thank you, and done I edited my post

Comment: $k = 3x + 5y$ and $k + 1= 3x + 5y$ should tip you off you did *somthing* wrong.  That means $k$ and $k+1$ are both the same thing!

Comment: Oh... I see what you mean. $k+1 = 3x' + 5y'$ for a *different* pair of numbers.  That's good! but you need to take into account what happens if $y = 0$ and you can't get $y' = 0-1$.

Comment: @fleablood But how does one derive to this 5y=5y−5+5?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Why would $5y = 5y - 5 + 5$ be relevant?  Why do you need $5y = 5y - 5 + 5?

Comment: Why do you start with $5y = 5y - 5 + 5$ which it true but utterly irrelevant so far as I can tell.  ANd why is the second line $5y = 5y - 1 + 5$ which is obviously false.  What are you *trying* to say?  Would it help you to use $3x = 3x - 6 +6$?

Answer (score 2):

A good induction argument should take you from the base case, as far as you want to go. You need to establish the $8$ cent case, and a rule that shows how to take the $k$ cent case, and produce the $k + 1$ cent case. You're missing the $8$ cent case, but that's easy: $8 = 3 + 5$.

Now, we should be able to apply your rule to make every subsequent number of cents. Your rule is as follows:
$$3x + 5y = k \implies 3(x + 2) + 5(y - 1) = k + 1.$$
Here's a question: how do you know that $y - 1$ is a sensible number of $5$ cent coins? To see this, let's try applying this rule to $8$ cents in order to get $9$ cents:
$$3 \cdot 1 + 5 \cdot 1 = 8 \implies 3 \cdot 3 + 5 \cdot 0 = 9.$$
This works out; three $3$ cent coins will make $9$ cents. Let's try again for $10$ cents:
$$3 \cdot 3 + 5 \cdot 0 = 9 \implies 5 \cdot 3 + 5 \cdot (-1) = 10.$$
Arithmetically, this is true, but we can't allow negative one $5$ cent coins! The combination $3(x + 1) + 5(y - 1)$ works fine, provided $y > 0$, but you haven't dealt with the $y = 0$ case!

Instead, I suggest first manually dealing with $8$, $9$, and $10$ individually. We have ways of making $8$ and $9$ already. To make $10$, we have
$$10 = 0 \cdot 3 + 2 \cdot 5.$$
Then, $11$ is just $8$ with $3$ more cents added on, $12$ is $9$ with another $3$ cents, similarly $13$ is $10$ with another $3$ cents, etc. If you do strong induction, and assume for a given $n$, $k$ cents can be made for every $8 \le k < n$, then appeal to $n - 3$, and add another $3$ cent coin to the collection. That is, provided $n > 10$; otherwise refer back to the three explicit cases.

Comment: But how does one derive to this 5y=5y−5+5? I'm confused at that part

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. I don't really use the fact that $5y = 5y - 5 + 5$ in the proof. The essence of the proof is to work out three cases, and keep adding $3$ cents to get the rest of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

$3*2 - 5*1 = 1$ and $2*5 - 3*3 = 1$.

So if $k = 3a + 5b$ we can get $k+1 = 3(a+2) + 5(b-1)$.  But that assumes $b > 0$.  What if $b = 0$?

Well then you can do $k + 1 = 3(a-3) + 5(b+2)$.  That that assumes $a > 2$.  What if $a \le 2$?

Well, you go back to square one and do $k+1 = 3(a+2) + 5(b-1)$.

... in short .....

If $a \le 2$ you do $k+1 = 3(a-3) + 5(b+2)$.

If $b = 0$ you do $k + 1 = 3(a+2) + 5(b-1)$.

If $a > 2$ and $b> 0$ then you do either one, it doesn't matter which.

But what if $b = 0$ *and* $a \le 2$?

Well that means $k = 3a + 5b \le 6< 8$.  That's below our base case.  We don't have to worry about it.

====== alternative ====

Don't do induction to show $k+1$ is possible.  Do induction to show $k + 3$ is possible.

Base **cases**(plural)

$k = 8;  k = 5*1+3*1$

$k = 9;  k = 5*0 + 3*3$

$k = 10; k = 5*2 + 3*0$.

If $k = 5a + 3b$ then $k + 3 = 5a + 3(b+1)$

That takes care of every case at least $8$.

$11$ is possible because $8$ is possible.  $12$ is possible because $9$ is possible.  $13$ is possible because $10$ is possible.  $14$ is possible because $11$ is possible.  And so on.